# NodeJS - Call Nested Function from inside another nested Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested-function

i have two nested functions, i want to call the second one inside the first one but i nodejs doesn't seem to recognize it.

```js
function Main(){
  this.NestedA = function(){
    console.log('Hello from A')
  }

  this.NestedB = function(){
    console.log('Hello from B')

    /* How to call NestedA from here? */
    /**
     * I tried
     * NestedA()
     * this.NestedA()
     */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `this`. Try this way:

```js
function Main(){
  const NestedA = function() {
    console.log('Hello from A')
  }

  const NestedB = function() {
    console.log('Hello from B');
    NestedA();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this? Really, you should not need `this`. Just change the declaration to normal function declarations, you might even use const assignment for functions like NestedC below.

```
function Main(){
  function NestedA(){
    console.log('Hello from A')
  }
  const NestedC= () => {
    console.log('Hello from A')
  }

  function NestedB(){
    console.log('Hello from B')
    NestedA();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also return the function that you want to call, and call it such as:

```
 function Main() {
  this.NestedA = function () {
    console.log("Hello from A");
  };

  return (this.NestedB = function () {
    console.log("Hello from B");
  });
}

Main2()(); //Hello from B
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `this`

Try this snippet

```
function Main(){
  NestedA = function(){
    console.log('Hello from A')
  }

  NestedB = function(){
    console.log('Hello from B')
     NestedA();
  }
NestedB();

}
Main();
```

Calling `Main()` 
`Main()` call `NestedB()` 
`NestedB()` call `NestedA()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Main(){
  var that = this;
  this.NestedA = function() {
    console.log('Hello from A')
  }

  this.NestedB = function() {
    console.log('Hello from B');
    that.NestedA();
  }
}

var m = new Main();
m.NestedB();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.